# Can someone spot the error in my code? My html is not adjusting to the changed values

Tags: javascript, html, input, error-handling, output

For some reason, my html is not adjusting to my JavaScript that I have put in. The tags are all right, but for some reason my website do8es not react to the change in the input box. *** Please help me spot the Problem! *** The converter code is given below, as well as the HTML.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
let VSWRout = document.getElementById('VSWRout');
let Mismatchout2 = document.getElementById('MisMatchOut2');
let RLin = document.getElementById('RLin1');

/**
 * @return {number}
 */
function RLintoVSWRout(){
    return Math.round((Math.pow(10,((parseFloat(RLin.value))/20)) + 1) / (Math.pow(10,((parseFloat(RLin.value))/20)) - 1) * 100) /100;
}
/**
 * @return {number}
 */
function RLintoMismatchout2(){
    return Math.round((-10 * Math.log10(Math.pow((Math.pow(10,(-parseFloat(RLin.value)/ 20))), 2)))*100) /100;
}
function RLconverter(){
    VSWRout.html = '<td id=VSWRout>' + RLintoVSWRout() + '</td>';
    Mismatchout2.html = '<td id=MisMatchOut2>' + RLintoMismatchout2() + '</td>'
}

RLin.addEventListener('change', RLconverter, false);
```

**HTML**

```
 <section>
      <!---VSWR, RL(dB), MismatchLoss(dB) -->
      <table id="VSWR,RL,MismatchLoss">
          <tr>
            <td>VSWR</td>
            <td>RL(dB)</td>
            <td>Mismatch Loss(dB)</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td><label for="VSWR"></label><input type="number" id="VSWR" min="1" /> </td>
            <td>later</td>
            <td>later</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="VSWRout"></td>
            <td><label for="RLin1"></label><input type="number" id="RLin1" min="0" /> </td>
            <td id="MisMatchOut2"></td>
          </tr>

      </table>      
    </section>
```

I am currently focusing on the last row.

Comment: Make sure you clear your cache.

Comment: If you have a solution, add an answer; don’t put that into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `RLconverter` function to use innerHTML instead of html:

Incorrect:

```
function RLconverter(){
    VSWRout.html = '<td id=VSWRout>' + RLintoVSWRout() + '</td>';
    Mismatchout2.html = '<td id=MisMatchOut2>' + RLintoMismatchout2() + '</td>'
}
```

Correct:

```
function RLconverter(){
    VSWRout.innerHTML = '<td id=VSWRout>' + RLintoVSWRout() + '</td>';
    Mismatchout2.innerHTML = '<td id=MisMatchOut2>' + RLintoMismatchout2() + '</td>'
}
```